# Django Rest Framework serialization of many generates NoneType instances of serialized relation

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm quite new on Django Rest Framework, and I've been trying to write a serializer for one of my models. For my project I intend to output the json result according to the JSON API Standards, and, for doing so, I am using the SerializerMethodField in which I call the method `get_data()` as follows:

## models.py

```
class Level(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    level_set = models.ManyToManyField(Level, blank=True)
```

## serializers.py

```
class LevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Level
        fields = ('data',)

    def get_data(self, instance):
        return {
            "type": "Level",
            "uuid": instance.id_key(),
            "attributes": {
                "name": instance.name,
            },
            "relationships": {
                "children": self.get_children_recursive(),
            },
        }

    def get_children_recursive(self, child=None):
        """
        Generates a tree of levels structured according to JSON API standards.
        """
        if not child:
            children = self.instance.get_children()
            level = self.instance
        else:
            children = child.get_children()
            level = child
        tree = {
            'data': {
                'type': 'Level',
                'uuid': level.id_key(),
                'attributes': {
                    'name': level.name,
                },
                'relationships': {
                    'children': [],
                    'parents': [],
                }
            }
        }
        for child in children:
            tree['data']['relationships']['children'].append(self.get_children_recursive(child))
        return tree

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    root_level_set = LevelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id_key', 'name', 'root_level_set')
```

The weird thing is that if I go to the shell and try to serialize an instance of Level it works fine, but trying to serialize a Group gives me an error at `get_children_recursive()` at line with the `if not child statement` saying that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_children'`. The outputs are these:

Run:

```
from core.serializers import LevelSerializer
from core.models import Level
lvl = Level.objects.all()[0]
serializer = LevelSerializer(lvl)
print(serializer.data)
```

Outputs the nested level and it's sublevels according to the JSON structure I designed following the JSON API Standards.

Although if I run:

```
from core.serializers import GroupSerializer
from core.models import Group
grp = Group.objects.all()[0]
serializer = GroupSerializer(grp)
print(serializer.data)
```

Outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/maumau/.virtualenvs/olist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 503, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/home/maumau/.virtualenvs/olist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 239, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/maumau/.virtualenvs/olist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 472, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/maumau/.virtualenvs/olist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 614, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/maumau/.virtualenvs/olist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 614, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/maumau/.virtualenvs/olist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 472, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/maumau/.virtualenvs/olist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1653, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "/mnt/SHARED-DRIVE/Workspace/interview-tests/work-at-olist/core/serializers.py", line 20, in get_data
    "children": self.get_children_recursive(),
  File "/mnt/SHARED-DRIVE/Workspace/interview-tests/work-at-olist/core/serializers.py", line 29, in get_children_recursive
    children = self.instance.get_children()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_children'
```

It doesn't seem to make sense for me that the serialization of Level it self possesses the attribute instance set while the serialization of Group, which calls the serialization of Level as well, does not. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why designing everything yourself? let djrf do some magic :)

```
class LevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    attributes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    relationships = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(self, instance):
        return "Level"

    def get_attributes(self, instance):
        return {
            "name": instance.name
        }

    def get_relationships(self, instance):
        return {
            "children": self.__class__(instance.get_children(), many=True).data,
            "parents": []
        }

    class Meta:
        model = Level
        fields = ('type', 'attributes', 'relationships')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    level_set = LevelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'level_set')
```

why your code does not work? because of wrong code:

1. look what is a difference in calling `LevelSerializer` in those 2 cases - one parameter - `many=True`; when `many=True` - serializer does not have `instance` property
2. beside (1), first run of `get_children_recursive` will duplicate first element as first child
3. using your approach you do not need `ModelSerializer` at all, because all is done manually - in such a case, simple `Serializer` will be better
4. by creating virtual `data` field - you are making your code more complex, why not use data directly to avoid dictionaries with one `data` key

my example code is missing `id_key` field - you had not documented it here, but adding it should be a breze

using extra module `rest_framework_recursive`, code can be simplified:

```
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField


class LevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    children = serializers.ListField(child=RecursiveField(), source='get_children')

    def get_type(self, instance):
        return "Level"

    class Meta:
        model = Level
        fields = ('type', 'name', 'children')
```

Comment: Flawless. Worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute name in serialzier: `root_level_set`. In model: `level_set`.

DRF tries to find attribute `root_level_set` in group, does not find it and replace it by `None`. Thats why you get such error.

Fix:

1. Rename `root_level_set` -> `level_set` in serializer.
2. Or add `source` to field: `root_level_set = LevelSerializer(source='level_set', many=True)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. The error us being thrown when I try to access the model instance attribute from within the LevelSerializer instance. I don't try to access the root_level_set or level_set. Also I tried your suggestion and it still gives me the same error. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The error takes place inside the LevelSerializer, not at GroupSerializer.